# how to do Integration testing in microservices architecture

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, integration-testing, microservices

I was looking for patterns/best practice for doing integration testing in microservices.  Below is quick description of my context.

1. microservice A  depends on
   a. azureAD for authentication
   b. Microservice B for authorization
2. microservice B talks to azure sql Db to CRUD for user/roles/permissions + exposes endpoints to check permission which is used by 1.  this service is also protected by azure AD authentication

What is the best approach to create integration test for such a case. ? Any references or guidance welcome. Some questions :

a. what to mock , what not to mock
b. setup teardown strategy
c. others

Comment: After a few months reflection, are there any comments you have about what you have learned about testing frameworks?

Answer (score 3):

There are three general approaches to consider:

1. Don't integration test. Just mock everything and unit test.
2. Integration test against a sandbox (non-PROD) deployment of the microservice using real data
3. Integration test against a PROD deploy using fake data (known by the other service as fake)

There are pros/cons with each.

3) Requires some cross-team coordination to ensure that every microservice has some known inputs that will be regarded as "test-only", but most accurately simulates a real use case.

2) Doesn't require as much cross-team coordination, and doesn't have the possibility of disruptive service or adding garbage data on accident.

1) is the most fragile, and only ensures that your application can handle the expected (at the time) input/output data.

Go for the best strategy that your organizations DevOps and Development maturity will support.

To answer your detailed questions:

- a. You only need to mock the integration with #1. #2 and #3 are real.
- b. Setup and teardown for #2 and #3 should simply be injecting the
  endpoint
- c. Test all of your use cases. Ensure that you hit each
  method call you consume.